# Good style for self commenting code without OOP

Tags: python

On the one hand, a framework bumps me to use functions rather than classes. It doesn't matter which framework it is.
On the other hand a self commenting code should be subdivided into a short subprograms with descriptive names.

This means that for a single function that can be reused we have to write several functions just for our code to be readable.

In case of using OOP it is not a problem at all. We organise a class and create private method in it (marked _ in front in case of Python).

But if we don't use OOP, these auxiliary functions are spread all over the module. They are much more numerous than functions that can be reused. And one can even get lost in them and forget that a function for this particular purpose already exists

Example:

```
def combine(str1, str2):
    return "{}_{}".format(str1, str2)

def get_salted_str(str):
    SALT = "slkdjghslkdjfghsldfghaaasd"
    return combine(str, SALT)


def get_salted_string(str):    
    return combine(str, get_salted_str(str))


def get_salted_peppered_string(str):
    salted_str = get_salted_str(str)
    PEPPER = "1234128712908369735619346"

    return "{}_{}".format(PEPPER, salted_str)
```

In the example there are two main functions: get_salted_string and get_salted_peppered_string.  They can be imported and reused. Everything else is just auxiliary functions. This is a fake example, don't be overenthusiastic about criticizing it.

As for the style: how can one distinguish between main and aux functions? If there are a lot of aux functions, everything becomes a mess.

Two questions:

1) Is it better to use underline symbol to mark unimported functions? Like this: _get_salted_str. Or how can we mark aux functions?
2). Is there any style guide mentioning solutions to this problem?

Comment: I usually use an "_" to mark such auxiliary functions. Also it's usually a good idea to use packages and modules to organize your code. E.g. if your module has already 324235 lines, split it up into packages and only export the relevant functions from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1), I'd say yes, a leading underscore is a well-known Python convention to show private-ness of names.

There is language support for it too, not just style guide: [the import statement docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) about 'import *' says:

> If __all__ is not defined, the set of public names includes all names found in the module’s namespace which do not begin with an underscore character ('_').

That said:

- Don't over do it, four or five lines for a function is fine, putting one liners in their own private functions often just makes code *harder* to read as the reader has to look around for those functions to understand what's happening exactly. And it's easy to make a mess, as you say.
- You can think of modules as a very similar concept to classes, in that they are *namespaces*. There is no real OO vs non-OO dichotomy here.
- It's also possible to put the module in a package, do whatever makes the module the most readable (forget underscores), maybe split the module into several, and then import only the functions that should be used from the outside into the package's `__init__.py` file. Then they can be imported directly from there, and nothing else can.

That's the distinction between "main" and "aux" functions: only those meant to be used from outside the module are "main".

Answer (score 1):

You could group your functions in different modules and make your help functions in a module called utils.py for example.

Or define the helper functions directly in your main function, if there are not a lot of them.